# Specs are passing locally but not on CircleCI, running poltergeist + phantomjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist, circleci

My specs are passing when I run then on my local setup as well as on my colleague's setup. But they refuse to pass on our CI.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: page.create_template_shift(user, day)
     Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
       Firing a click at co-ordinates [960, 267.5] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html.js.no-flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.no-webgl.touch.no-geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.no-indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.no-csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.no-video.no-audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths body.templates.show.modal-open div.modal-backdrop.fade.in' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

And here is the screenshot from `capybara-screenshot`:

[image]

As you can see I'm trying to click on "Save" button but it can not because there seems to be a div that is black/faded that is covering the entire screen.

How can this happen only in their environment? And why is this happening?

EDIT: Updated image and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a package in my `bower.json` file that was breaking the specs. 
When running it in CircleCI the latest package was downloaded due to the `~` character right before the version number inside `bower.json`.

I had an older package on my local environment.

Comment: I've faced a similar situation and it's fixed after `bundle update`. I didn't hunt exactly which gem version caused this error, though local and CircleCI's fresh `bundle install` had some different version of gems. (I'm using rails)

Comment: My problem was the tzinfo-data gem, so i removed and it worked.